# How to create issue dependencies/links in Jira (3.13)?

Tags: dependencies, bug-tracking, jira

We recently switched from other bug tracking software to Jira (3.13 currently ).

We need to set **issue linking** in a manner that my task start time **depends on other colleague's issue** and I can not start **until he resolves his issue**...

I goolged and found that this kind of thing is integrated in newer versions :/ Maybe we need some plugin, make some custom field, enable something in administration part...

Any help would be appreciated...

(please retag/add jira and bug-tracking tags or whatever)

Answer (score 1):

It seams that this is not implemented yet, but watching this issues might help to determine when it will be done:

http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-647

http://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-1383